# Safari Extension Locks Session

Tags: session, safari-extension

I'm building a Safari Extension that extends the functionality of my base website.

One of the more basic functionalities is that the user needs to be able to log into our website from the extension.  This is required because in order for the extension to interact with our APIs the user needs to be logged in.

Anyways, logging in from the extension is working mostly great.  I've got a popup window that contains a login form, then does an AJAX request to our login API, and closes itself if the login was successful.  Works great.

Except for one thing - if I have my website open in any tab when I open up the popup login form, it seems that the actual browser's session doesn't get logged in.  The extension completes the login API request successfully and can make authenticated calls to our other API functions, but if I manually browse to one of our APIs it says that I'm not logged in.

I'm not sure how to describe it, because it really doesn't make sense.  It almost seems as if the safari extension is locking the session (cookies?) of the pages under it.

Has anyone ever heard of this, or can possibly think of what might be causing it?